# Yii 2 CRUD url issue

Tags: php, yii2, backend, crud

I have created a model class product and active queries and generated CRUD using gii.
here is the structure.

```
backend
 common/models
  product

 controllers
  ProductContoller
 
 views/layouts
   product
    _form
    _search
   create
   index
   update
   view
```

Also I have enabled mu urlManager inside main.php

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
        ],
    ],
```

when I try to access the model using yii2-ecommerce.localhost/product

getting 404 error.

Comment: Could you show full your config file and nginx / apache config of your local domain ?

Answer (score 0):

You should store the product view elem in  `views/product`  and not in `view/layout`

```
views/product
_form
_search
```

create
index
update
view

view/layout is for `layout`   the layouts are formatted view container for specific view